# How to exclude current clicked item if it has a specific class already from jQuery .each loop?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to capture all the links which have a class "current" in a way.

Here is my code:

```
$('#filter-by li ul a').live('click',function(e){

    var terms_ids = '';
    var taxonomies = '';
    $('#filter-by li ul a.current').each( function() {
        terms_ids = terms_ids + $(this).parent().attr('class').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') + ',';
        taxonomies = taxonomies + $(this).closest('.tax-parent-li').find('ul li:first a').attr('rel').replace(/default_/, '') + ',';
    });

});
```

When the link is clicked, I wanted it to calculate/capture all elements which have the class current, I used each loop for this. But I want to make an exclusion and not sure how to do it, **I do not want it to take into account the current clicked link if the current clicked link already has **.current*** class.*

There are multiple links with current class, I want to avoid the one being clicked if it already has current class previously.

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what's required without more markup and information, but you may find [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) useful.

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .not() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements. The supplied selector is tested against each element; the elements that don't match the selector will be included in the result.

For example,

```
$('sel').not(this).each(...)
```

will call the `.each` callback on every element matching the selector *except* for the current element (i.e. `this`).